# The connect (in a QT project) doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm starting to create my first multithread application, using the QT libraries.

Following the qt guide about QTcpServer and QTcpSocket, i wrote a server application that create the connection with this constructor:

```
Connection::Connection(QObject *parent) : QTcpServer(parent)
{
    server = new QTcpServer();
    QString ipAddress;

    if (ipAddress.isEmpty())
        ipAddress = QHostAddress(QHostAddress::LocalHost).toString();

    if (!server->listen(QHostAddress(ipAddress),41500))
    {
        qDebug() << "Enable to start server";
        server->close();
        return;
    }

    connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(incomingConnection()));
}
```

This is the incomingConnection() function which create a new thread everytime a new client try to connect:

```
void Connection::incomingConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket();
    socket = this->nextPendingConnection();

    MyThreadClass *thread = new MyThreadClass(socket, server);
    qDebug() << "connection required by client";
    if (thread != 0)
    {
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    thread->start();
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "Error: Could not create server thread.";
}
```

Now, this is MyThreadClass:

```
MyThreadClass::MyThreadClass(QTcpSocket *socket, QTcpServer *parent) : QThread(parent)
{
    tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();
    database = new Db();
    blockSize = 0;

    tcpSocket = socket;

    qDebug() << "creating new thread";
}


MyThreadClass::~MyThreadClass()
{
    database->~Db();
}


void MyThreadClass::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Thread created";
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(dataAvailable()));
    exec();
}


void MyThreadClass::dataAvailable()
{
    qDebug() << "data available";
    QDataStream in(tcpSocket);
    in.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);

    if (blockSize == 0) {
        if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < (int)sizeof(qint16))
            return;
        in >> blockSize;
    }

    if (tcpSocket->bytesAvailable() < blockSize)
        return;

    QString string;
    in >> string;

    //[...]

 }
```

The code compiles fine but when i start a client (after starting the server), i receive the following error by server:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::readyRead() to QThread::dataAvailable()
```

Then the server cannot receive data by the client.

does anyone have any idea?

thanks in advance
Daniele

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `socket` belongs to first thread, and you're passing it through newly created thread, and inside, you're doing `tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();` which seems not able to reallocate data outside current thread.

Comment: Where did you learn C++? Do you know anything about heap and stack? You're leaking memory. Also you're calling destructor manualy instead of using delete.

Another thing is that even if connect to readyRead would work fine, your slot would be called in different thread then you're expecting. There is plenty of things to fix in your code. Also could you provide MyThreadClass declaration? On your place I would start from learning some C++ basics (like memory managment). You're doing so much things wrong, that I wouldn't even bother with your connect problem until you get some C++ basics

Comment: `tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();` and then `tcpSocket = socket;`. Why??? Why would you do that??

Comment: you're right. That code is the result of many changes, so there are a lot of mistakes...so sorry for that...  However if cancel the "tcpSocket = new QTcpSocket();" instruction, the problem doesn't change...

Comment: why do you create a `QTcpServer` when you inherit it? it's awkward!! i'm not mentioning other problems because someone have already told you... "many changes" is not an excuse to leave that kind of  garbage in the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socket = this->nextPendingConnection();
```

should be:

```
socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
```

because you are using the `server` member and not `this` as the active `QTcpServer`, the class `Connection` shouldn't even inherit from `QTcpServer`, but only from `QObject`.

Also, you are misusing `QThread`. You should read [Signals and slots across threads](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects#913fb94dd61f1a62fc809f8d842c3afa), and probably [Threads and the SQL Module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-modules.html#threads-and-the-sql-module), if `Db` is using the QtSql module.

Comment: That mistake comes from poor C++ knowledge. Thats why I didn't point it out in the beginning.

Comment: #Kamil Klimek: I know that, because i learnt C++ alone. Probably if i knew very well like you C++, then i wouldn't need to ask anything here. Furthermore, if you don't want, nobody force you to answer

Comment: #alexisdm: Thank you very much. I knew there were a lot of mistakes, but, following your advice, now the project proceeds quite well. Actually server and client communicate as i want.